# Selectize disable sifter

Tags: selectize.js

I am trying to implement [selectize](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) javascript library. It works but my question is how do I disable the `sifter` option. The problem is by default `sifter` option is enabled and if I have words like `Asset` in the option, it will be filtered to become `et`.

I tried with below but doesn't work:

```
score: function () {
    return function () {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selectize is very dependent on `sifter`, I don't see a easy way to disable that, and I think if you do that, you get rid of most of (maybe the entire) `selectize` search feature.

`sifter` has an config option in its last version that can help you to achieve what you want, the config option is `respect_word_boundaries`:

> If true, matches only at start of word boundaries (e.g. the beginning of words, instead of matching the middle of words)

The problem is `selectize` doesn't not use the latest version, so you have to use the not all-in-all bundled version of `selectize` called "default".

Make sure you're using `sifter` version `0.6.0`.

I tried to do some tweaks using plugins on `selectize` to get this working. Check the result below:

```js
Selectize.define('change_search', function(options) {
  var self = this;
  this.getSearchOptions = (function() {
    var original = self.getSearchOptions();
    return function() {
      original['respect_word_boundaries'] = true;
      return original;
    };
  })();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').selectize({
    plugins: ['change_search']
  });
});
```

```css
.search {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/microplugin/0.0.3/microplugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sifter/0.6.0/sifter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/selectize.min.js"></script>

<div class='search'>
  <select placeholder="Choose one option..." id="search" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="asset">Asset</option>
    <option value="etc">Etcetera</option>
    <option value="etymology">Etymology</option>
    <option value="yet">Yet</option>
  </select>
</div>
```